# Microsoft Graph API Beta版を使って通話の作成に401 permissions エラーが発生しました。

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Graphエクスプローラーで下記の様な内容で試しました。

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/app/calls
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "callbackUri": "https://bot.contoso.com/api/calls",
  "mediaConfig": {
    "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.serviceHostedMediaConfig",
    "preFetchMedia": [
      {
        "uri": "https://cdn.contoso.com/beep.wav",
        "resourceId": "1D6DE2D4-CD51-4309-8DAA-70768651088E"
      },
      {
        "uri": "https://cdn.contoso.com/cool.wav",
        "resourceId": "1D6DE2D4-CD51-4309-8DAA-70768651088F"
      }
    ]
  },
  "source": {
    "identity": {
      "application": {
        "id": "8A34A46B-3D17-4ADC-8DCE-DC4E7D572698"
      }
    },
    "languageId": "languageId-value",
    "region": "region-value"
  },
  "subject": "Test Call",
  "targets": [
    {
      "identity": {
        "user": {
          "id": "550fae72-d251-43ec-868c-373732c2704f",
          "tenantId": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47",
          "displayName": "Heidi Steen"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "tenantId": "tenantId-value"
}
```

うち、application id、user id、tenantIdを実在のコードに置き換えていました。
下記Azure Active Directoryアプリケーションの権限も設定しています。
Calls.AccessMedia.All
Calls.Initiate.All
Calls.InitiateGroupCall.All
Calls.JoinGroupCall.All
Calls.JoinGroupCallAsGuest.All

しかし、以下の様なリスポンスが帰ってきます：
失敗 - 状態コード 401, 371ms Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions. 
応答プレビュー：

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "{\"errorCode\":\"9000\",\"message\":\"Unsupported AAD Identity.\",\"instanceAnnotations\":[]}",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "31afb007-2915-4829-95e4-35f392d3d8b4",
            "date": "2019-07-16T04:28:38"
        }
    }
}
```

権限設定は足りないでしょうか？
ちなみに、実行者のラインセンスは　O365 E1　です

Comment: 関係無いかもしれませんが、こんな通知があります。「 **重大な変更:Microsoft Graph ベータ版の通話とオンライン会議 API の更新プログラム** いくつかの重大な変更を含む、Microsoft Graph ベータ版の通話とオンライン会議 API の複数の変更を発表します。」[Breaking changes: Calls and online meetings API updates in Microsoft Graph beta](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/blogs/breaking-changes-calls-and-online-meetings-api-updates-in-microsoft-graph-beta/)

Comment: 同じく関係無いかもしれませんが、こんな記事があります。[Privileged Identity Management](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/graph/api/resources/privilegedidentitymanagement-root?view=graph-rest-beta), [Microsoft Teams (beta) API: Looks like you may not have the permissions for this call. Please modify your permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44460717/9014308)